# Mount a dropbox directory without installing the dropbox application

Tags: command-line, ssh, directory, scp, dropbox

This is most likely to be a duplicate question, but I could not find a simple answer for my problem.

My situation is as follows: I have multiple accounts on different computing clusters. I want to have a common directory where I can save some files and scripts. In particular, I want a way to simply access a `Dropbox` directory with a passwordless connection.

So for instance, if I am logged to one of my accounts and I want to run a `python` script to process some of my files, I will like to do something like this:

```
python /dropbox_path/script.py
```

Where `/dropbox_path/` is a web link to my `Dropbox` account.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.dropdav.com/ ...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote CloudFusion [1], which can be mounted on any emtpy directory. If the directory is not empty, you need to move the contents before mounting it and copy it back after mounting. It is not the same as the sync deamon, since it uses a size limited cache instead of storing copies of all files locally. Also, it is lazy in getting files from Dropbox; you first need to access the file contents before it is cached (so calling your script the first time might be slow). It does not support symbolic links yet. Other restrictions are mentioned in the documentation.

1. https://github.com/joe42/CloudFusion